# Read from an input file, check and store some of it information in arrays in C

Tags: c, arrays, fopen, fgets

I've got input files like these:

```
The Branch PC is e05f56f8

The Branch Type is branch_type_1

The Branch is Taken

The Branch Target is e045ac20

jal__        1141512
```

```
The Branch PC is e045ac44

The Branch Type is branch_type_1

The Branch is Taken

The Branch Target is e05f57d4

jal__        1562101
```

```
The Branch PC is e05f57fc

The Branch Type is branch_type_1

The Branch is Taken

The Branch Target is e05f578c

jal__        1562083
```

I need to get the information of the branch PC from line "`The Branch PC is ********`", and whether the branch is Taken for Not Taken from line "`The Branch is Taken/Not Taken`". And store this two information into a 2-D array for all the Branches.

I was wondering after I use `fopen`, how can I check each line to get the information I want.

Comment: [**What have you tried?**](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you want something like:

```
char hm[20], line[128];
FILE *fd=fopen("lol", "r");
while(fgets(line, 128, fd)) {
    if(strstr(line, "PC")) sscanf(line, "The Branch PC is %s\n", &hm);
    if(strstr(line, "Not Taken")) printf("%s Not taken !\n", hm);
    else if(strstr(line, "Taken")) printf("%s Taken !\n", hm);
}
fclose(fd);
```

Storing into array shouldn't be a problem after parsing..

Answer (score 0):

You can read until a line terminator is detected like \r\n or \n depending on windows vs Linux. Then read n characters into each line to the line terminator.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it would be a lot easier if you use some bash scripting to perform a preprocessing of your text file, then let the C program work over the output of the script